# Disable a button until selection is made

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have this section in my website:

[image]

There is a drop down list of environments and an area for a user to input a Zip Code. What I am trying to achieve is making the button disabled until a selection is made from the list. Here is my code:

```
<select id="myList">
                <option selected value="defaultValue">Select..</option>
                <option value="http://eddmapi-dev.usps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP">DEV</option>
                <option value="http://eddmapi-sit.usps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP">SIT</option>  
                <option value="http://eddmapi-cat.usps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP">CAT</option>
                <option value="http://eddmapi.usps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP">PROD</option>
            </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="input-text-wrapper input-text-lg">
                    Input ZIP CODE :
                    <span class="input-cap-left"></span>
                    <span class="input-field">              
                    <input id="Zip_code" type="text" name="address">
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-cap-right"></span>
                </div>
                <br>
            <button type="button" onclick="selectZIP(Zip_code.value)">Execute</button>
```

Here is my code for the list selection:

```
require(['dojo/on', 'dojo/query'],
    function (on, query) {
    document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = false;
        on(query('#myList'), 'change', function (e) {
            gpURL = e.target.value;
            console.log('Environment changed: ' + '"' + gpURL + '"');
        });
    });
```

Where would I place the code:

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You have tagged this jQuery, but you are using Dojo. It is possible to mix the two but that seems like trouble... why not just do it in Dojo?</strike>

@Stephen's suggestions are sound, and the same can be accomplished in Dojo just as easily (there are probably other/better ways):

```
require(['dojo/on', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/dom-attr'],
  function (on, dom, domAttr) {
    var execute = dom.byId('execute');
    domAttr.set(execute, 'disabled', true);
    on(dom.byId('myList'), 'change', function (e) {
      gpURL = e.target.value;
      console.log('Environment changed: ' + '"' + gpURL + '"');
      domAttr.set(execute, 'disabled', false);
    });
  });
```

Comment: not using JQuery, that was added by an admin as a tag after the first comment mentioned JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this a couple of ways. One way is to have that button invisible/disabled until the user has made a selection. Using jQuery you could set a listener which responded when the user made a change.

To start, give the button an ID so you can refer to it:

```
<button id="execute" type="button" onclick="selectZIP(Zip_code.value)">Execute</button>
```

Set the button to be disabled or invisible by default:

```
#execute {display: none;}
```

Set a listener to enable/display the button when a selection is made:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myList").on('change', function() {
       //ideally you would validate that the selection was valid here
       $("#execute").show(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function on event when you choose a item that is on `onchange` event of the select box and in that function you have to write

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = false;
```

Initially give id for the button as buttonId or which you prefer and set property `disabled="disabled"`